# Arrastar div para outra div e redimensionar ao soltar!

Tags: div, resize

Boa noite, galera! basicamente o que estou querendo fazer é arrastar uma div (#mainmsg) para dentro de uma outra div (#msgprivhere), porém preciso que, ao soltar, ela seja redimensionada. Apenas gostaria de saber se isso é possível. Estou iniciando na área de web desenvolvimento, e sou muito leigo.
desde já agradeço!
não tenho preferencia por linguagem não. Se existir uma possibilidade, eu gostaria de tentar.
Agradeço a quem puder responder!

```
                <div id="scroll" >
                    <div id="hidden">
                        <div class="rcvmsg" id="mainchat">
                            <div class="mainmsg">
                                <span class="nickname"> Oliver Motokh </span>
                                <span style="float:right"> 12:34 pm </span>
                                <span> heeooooyuuuo</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="msgprivhere">
                        <div class="privmss">
                            <div id="rcvprivuser">
                                <div id="privuser">
                                    <span class="nicknamepriv">Oliver Motokh </span>
                                    <span style="float:right"> 12:34 pm </span>
                                    <span> heeeeyyyyyyooooooooooooy</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.
Você pode utilizar a função `onDrop` do Javascript:

```
 <div ondrop="Funcao(evento)"></div>
```

Na função você redimensiona utilizando jQuery, manipulando o css da div. 
Espero ter ajudado.

** Atualização
Conforme solicitado, estou colocando um exemplo mais completo de como fazer isso, usando jQuery:

No HTML:

```
<div id="movimento" ondrop="mover()"></div>
```

No JavaScript:

```
function mover() {
   $("#movimento").css({"width":"500px","height":"400px"});
}
```